# Google Analytics API PHP "The OAuth client was disabled"

Tags: php, oauth, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm having trouble integrating google analytics api with my php web site.  I'm trying to show the data on my website without having users log into google, so I'm using the service account method.  I also tried to use the hello world analytics code, and that gives me the same error.

Here's the complete error message: 
Error refreshing the OAuth2 token, message: '{ "error" : "disabled_client", "error_description" : "The OAuth client was disabled." }'

```
<?php 
require_once('google-api/Google_Client.php');
require_once('google-api/contrib/Google_AnalyticsService.php');

session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$KEY_FILE = 'path_to_key_file/123-privatekey.p12'; //KEY FILE     

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName('AppName'); //APP NAME

$account = 'abcd@developer.gserviceaccount.com'; //FOUND IN CLIENT SERVICE EMAIL ADDRESS



$client->setAssertionCredentials(new Google_AssertionCredentials(
  $account,
  array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly'),
  file_get_contents($KEY_FILE))
);

$client->setClientId('123.apps.googleusercontent.com'); //CLIENT ID
$client->setAccessType('offline_access');  // this may be unnecessary?


if (!$client->getAccessToken() && false) {
  $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
  print "<a class='login' href='$authUrl'>Connect Me!</a>";

} else {
  // Create analytics service object. See next step below.
    if ($client) 
    {
       // Create analytics service object. See next step below.
        //$analytics = new Google_AnalyticsService($client);
        //runDemo($analytics);
        $ids = "ga:" . "46052980";
        $startDate="2013-12-12";
        $endDate="2013-12-20";
        $metrics="ga:visits";
        try {
            $analytics = new Google_AnalyticsService($client);
            $results = $analytics->data_ga->get($ids,
                            $startDate,
                                $endDate,'ga:visits');
            /*echo '<b>Number of visits this week:</b> ';
            echo $results['totalsForAllResults']['ga:visits'];
            */
        } catch(Exception $e) {
            echo 'There was an error : - ' . $e->getMessage();
        }


    } else {
        echo "error";
        echo $key;
    }
}

if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
  $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
  echo $_SESSION['token'];
}

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use OAuth2 now. Have a look at the [sample code for PHP](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/wiki/Samples#Google_Analytics_API). Note that you have to register your app in the Google APIs Console first to get a client id, client secret, and API key.